# Determine trigger of workbookopen

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to determine how the WorkbookOpen event is triggered? Can it differentiate among firing from code or mouse click in windows explorer or File -> Open?

I have several workbooks with a macro that opens multiple files which in turn fires the workbookOpen event. I don't want the workbookOpen event to fire if it's triggered via code. I do want it to fire when I open them via mouse click.

Putting something like

```
If Dir(wb.Path & "\debug.txt") <> "" Then Exit Sub
```

in the open event and keeping an empty file called "debug.txt" doesn't suffice because the workbooks the macro opens share the same directory. My current workbookOpen event is below.

```
Private Sub AppEvent_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook)

If wb.VBProject.Protection <> 1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

Call unlockVBA(wb)

End Sub
```

Maybe there's an API for this? I am on 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Application.EnableEvents` property to disable events, open the workbooks and then turn events back on again.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
' Open the workbooks
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Wouldn't that disable all events even if it was fired via mouse click?

Comment: You said in your post "I have several workbooks with a macro that opens multiple files which in turn fires the workbookOpen event." You add the `EnableEvents` code in those macros before & after your code opens the workbooks. Because you turn events off & back on again within the same code it doesn't affect anything else such as manually opening a file afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! It worked ^_^ However, it seems events are permanently disabled somehow but I can play around with that.

Comment: Events were not disabled. The macro closed my personal.xlsb where events were set to fire XD